# Fullcalendar events.php not returning a JSON object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to send a JSON object back to my fullcalendar ajax request and instead it's just returning an array. I'm new to JSON, and PHP, but I've done as much research as I can and haven't found anything useful.

**events.php**

```
<?php
// List of events
$json = array();

// Query that retrieves events
$requete = "SELECT * FROM `evenement` ORDER BY `id`";

 // connection to the database
require_once 'mysqli_connect.php';

// Execute the query
$resultat = $dbc->query($requete) or die(print_r($dbc->errorInfo()));

// sending the encoded result to success page
    $tempjson =  json_encode($resultat->fetch_all(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
    $tempjson = str_replace('"false"', 'false', $tempjson);
    echo $tempjson;

?>
```

**data being returned**

```
[["1","title","2015-07-26 00:00:00","2015-07-26 00:00:00","","1"]]
```

So, my question is, why is it not returning in a correct JSON key/value pair format?

And I don't think the issue is with the jQuery, but just in case...

**ajax call from calendar.js**

```
eventSources: [

     {
         url: '/php/events.php',
         type: 'GET',
         data: {},
         error: function (data) {
             alert('There was an error while fetching events!');
             console.log(data);
         }
     }
],
```

Comment: remove this line `$tempjson = str_replace('"false"', 'false', $tempjson);` and can you also paste the result of `$resultat->fetch_all()`

Comment: `var_dump($resultat->fetch_all(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));`

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> array(6) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(5) "title" [2]=> string(19) "2015-07-26 00:00:00" [3]=> string(19) "2015-07-26 00:00:00" [4]=> string(0) "" [5]=> string(1) "1" } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, solution is to loop the result from mysql and generate the required array.
Basically idea is to make sure your `.php` generates a valid JSON object as required by full-calendar. Accepted value for eventSources are mentioned in their [doc](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/eventSources/)

```
    // Query that retrieves events
    $requete = "SELECT * FROM `evenement` ORDER BY `id`";

     // connection to the database
    require_once 'mysqli_connect.php';

    // Execute the query
    $resultat = $dbc->query($requete) or die(print_r($dbc->errorInfo()));

    // sending the encoded result to success page
        while($row = $resultat->fetch_assoc()){
            $array[] = $row;
        }
        $tempjson =  json_encode($array);
        $tempjson = str_replace('"false"', 'false', $tempjson);
        echo $tempjson;

?>
```

I think you are making `eventSources` complicated. Try simple one:

```
eventSources: [
    '/php/events.php'
]
```

Default ajax options will be handled by fullcalendar.

Comment: I'm still getting the exact same array, no JSON. So there must be something wrong with the json_encode function, but how would I debug that?

Comment: I highly doubt there is anything wrong with `json_encode`. Before genrating JSON, check the `array`. What function of `mysqli` will generate the required array. I have updated the doc link in my answer. Sorry I am not much helpful to you. But I am sure the array isn't populated properly.

Comment: You are actually more helpful than you think, I looked at that link, and changed my code to  this...
    $array = mysqli_fetch_all($resultat, $resulttype = MYSQLI_ASSOC);

... and got this...
    
    {"id":"1","title":"title","start":"2015-07-26 00:00:00","end":"2015-07-26 00:00:00","url":"","allDay":"1"}

...but the fullcalendar ajax function still didn't like that. BUT IT'S A START!

Comment: @StillLearningGuy Glad I could help you in some way. :)

Comment: I had that originally, the purpose of making it more complicated was to make it easier to debug, otherwise I wouldn't get the error alert message. I'll keep messing with it, and if I find the solution before someone else, I'll post it.